# My changes in mystyle.css (vanilla5 skin in pmwiki) doesnt work

Tags: css, skins, pmwiki

So, I've customized my mystyle.css (in vanilla5 skin in pmwiki). I only changed the color from #33F to #abff33.

```
/*
 * Vanilla5
 * A skin for PmWiki 2  (http://pmwiki.org)
 * Version 1.0.8  (2015-03-24)
 * Copyright (c) 2015 Paul Wiegmans(p.wiegmans@inter.nl.net)
 * you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published
 * by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 */

/*  === Add your own custom style rules below === */

/* Links get a clear color, Links blue, visited purple */
a {
    color: #abff33;
}
a:visited {
    color: #909
}

/* === codeblokken === */
code, pre {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

I published my changes and my server shows me also that my changes have been accepted. But if I go to my browser my changes are somehow overwriten by the original content (back to color #33F). I have no idea why. It also doesnt matter what I change (adding comments etc.).

Comment: Have you done a hard refresh to bypass the cache? If so, what do the browser dev tools show to be the source of the bad styling?

Comment: oh ... that did the trick. Thank you very much :)